# HTML5 iPhone Safari Mobile visualize something rather than quicktime symbol when creating an audio tag

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

I'm writing a very simple webpage in html5 for iPhone.
the page is this one
    
        
        Not Working

Everything works but in the page from the iPhone i see the quicktime logo with a slash on it
and if i tap on it the player shows up the play button and in the background there is the quicktime logo. is it possible to replace the logos with a personal image? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the  tag with CSS and instead create an HTML element that will launch the quicktime player with a JavaScript onclick event.

Something like:

```
<audio src="track.mp3" controls></audio>
<div id="play-button">Play</div>

<script>
function playAudio() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    audioPlayer.play();
}

var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
button.addEventListener("click",playAudio,false);
</script>
```

As for displaying a visual/image within the external quicktime player, please check out my answer in a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601420/embedding-html5-audio-in-a-mobilesafari-webapp-is-it-possible-to-load-an-image/2670748#2670748).

Comment: i tried the trick you've posted but seems that mobilesafari cannot play audio tags without the quicktime externalplayer, if i visualize the page on safari for mac works fine but with mobilesafari nothing happens when i tap on the button!

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a web application to use only on the iPhone I strongly suggest you to use the fantastic

> [jQTouch framework](http://www.jqtouch.com).

then you can simple have a link to the mp3 file and it will play normally.

Answer (score 0):

In the video tag, set the poster to the image that you want to display.

Linda